# What does ${1%..} mean in this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I got script like this,

```
latex $1
asy ${1%.tex}.asy
```

I know if `$1=test.tex`, then `${1%.tex}.asy` will be `test-1.asy`, but what does `1%.` mean here? And if I want `${1%.tex}.asy` to be `test.asy`, what should I do?

Comment: `$1` is the first positional variable passed to the shell script at run time. `%.tex` removes the shortest matching `.tex` from behind. I am not sure how are you getting `test-1.asy` output from what you have shown above. It should yield your desired output.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the reason that I got `test-1.asy` has something to do with my software configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter%word}
>
> ${parameter%%word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

So if `$1` expands to `text.tex` then `${1%.tex}` expands to `text`.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide arguments to your script, e.g.:

```
myscript one two three
```

Those arguments are assigned to positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.  In the example above, `$1` would be assigned to `one` and `$2` to `two`, etc. The code `${1%.tex}.asy` is just operating on the variable `$1`: it returns a string with the suffix `.tex` removed and replaced it with `.asy`.